# How can I figure out where to link a missing template in Posts#new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#new Showing /Users/Tish/code/bloccit/app/views/posts/new.html.erb where line #18 raised:

Missing partial posts/_form, application/_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:   * "/Users/Tish/code/bloccit/app/views"   * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views" Extracted source (around line #18): 15 16 17 18 19 20 21

          <div class="col-md-8">

           <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post } %>       
         </div>
    </div>

Rails.root: /Users/Tish/code/bloccit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace app/views/posts/new.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb__1906244960834792437_2160461360'
```

Comment: Do u have a `_form.html.erb` inside `views/posts` ?

Comment: > yes, I created that in view/posts  
\
<%= form_for [topic, post] do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
   </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.label :body %>
         <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
       </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
         </div>
         
 <% end %>

Comment: >sorry I can't seem to get the format cleaner!

Comment: When posting more code, just edit your original question with an update.

Answer (score 1):

In `app/views/posts/new.html.erb`

```
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

In the `app/views/posts/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <%= f.label :title %> 
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %> 
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <%= f.label :body %> 
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %> 
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %> 
  </div> 
<% end %>
```